# What is the free abelian group on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups, free-abelian-group

I learnt that the **free abelian group on a set $X$** is the group $(\operatorname{Hom}(X, \mathbb{Z}), +)$. Okay, this sounds all right, but I also know the famous result that $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not free abelian. Since $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}=\operatorname{Hom}({\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}})$, I am pretty confused and I have two questions:

1. Are the concepts of the "free abelian group on some set" and that of "free abelian group" (this is the one where we take the definition as that of a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module) two different things?
2. What is the free abelian group on $\mathbb{N}$, since it doesn't seem that $\operatorname{Hom}({\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}})$ is what we are looking for?

Comment: Wherever you "learned" that, it's a pretty bad lesson. It does not specify what category $\mathrm{Hom}$ is being taken on (presumably sets), and if it is sets, then it is incorrect for infinite $X$. It should be "functions of finite support".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah, sorry for the bad $\operatorname{Hom}$ notation, that one was on me (my lecturer used the $\operatorname{Fun}$ notation for the set of functions, but I didn't know whether it was a widespread notation).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The free Abelian group on a set $X$ is not given by the set of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. It is given by the subset of those functions that take a nonzero value on only finitely many inputs. If you re-do your investigations with that change, everything should make a lot more sense.